# Squashing and merging from already squashed branch

Tags: git

I have 5 git commits which I have already squashed and merged . But I found couple of other things which I need to push into the same branch ( creating another branch is an hassle . So I pushed two more commits into the same branch and trying to squash them again on top of the earlier squashed `ALL Tests` . How do I do that ?

[image]

Comment: Why did you reset main onto feature/test? That is not where it belongs. You've destroyed the key relationship between main and origin/main.

Answer (score 0):

Just rebase them:

```
# first, rebase
git rebase main~2 main --onto origin/main
# now squash
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit -m "Whatever comment is appropriate"
```

Now `main` is a single revision on top of `origin/main`

Or, the UI-based way, also with rebase, but interactive

```
git rebase -i main~2 main --onto origin/main
```

You will get a list of the 2 commits, leave the first one as `pick`, set the second one to `squash`, save and exit.... you will get a UI where you will have to set the comment of the *single* commit that will be the squashed commit that you want. Set something appropriate, save and exit and you are done.

Comment: Fails to grapple with the key issue which is why main has become unrelated to origin/main. The op should not be squashing directly onto origin/main in the first place.

Comment: You know I would actually ask _why do you have a local main in the first place?_ :-D But anyway.

Comment: I know you would! Hey, you've got one convert anyway. I just did a lecture in my company about how I use git without pull and no local branches except my own feature branches.

Comment: I see your point . I was trying to setup in right way but have messed it up

Comment: @matt Now that you bring it up... if I have a convert.... I am one 1 step closer in the 3-step recipe to becoming filthy rich: 1 - get a convert 2 - convert many more people.... the tithing kind 3 - get filthy rich.

Comment: Sounds like a plan!